# Whatsapp update not getting deleted

Tags: uninstallation, whatsapp-messenger

I noticed my contacts list have been jumbled up meaning,
many contacts name are displayed with a common name.

So I erased all the phone data and factory reset.

Still the **WhatsApp** update icon is present and I am not able to delete it.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What do you mean, the "update icon"? [Do you mean a notification](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/52789/12442), or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Whatsapp is installed on the `/system` partition on your device. Which means, your device manufacturer decided to include the app in the device firmware. A factory reset can only remove the apps which you installed yourself which are present on the `/data` partition. To remove system apps you need to need to root your device and delete the app from the `/system/app/` directory.

Comment: Any app not removed/removable from the device will report a notification for a version update. It will even automatically update if that setting remains enabled in Google Play Store.

Comment: He was trying to factory reset to uninstall the app.