# WhatsApp Settings in Samsung S3 - Where do I find it?

Tags: notifications, whatsapp-messenger, app-icons

I use WhatsApp on my Samsung S3. I have some questions:

1. I can't find any settings option. I reinstalled the app and still cannot find the settings option anywhere. Am I missing something?
2. Is there any setting for showing notifications on the icon (new messages received, etc.)?

Comment: Showing notifications on the icon? Like in iPhone? Android doesn't work like that. Notifications are displayed at the top (notification bar).

Comment: There is a really simple answer for this. The settings button isn't on the screen, but rather on the phone itself. People often forget that the phone has those 4 buttons : Settings, home, back, and search.

Answer (score 1):

Apps on Android don't change their icon to show that there are new notifications, the notifications appear in the [Notification Bar](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/52790/156) at the top of the screen instead, so that they're always available at a glance, even when you're running other apps.

In Android apps manage their own notifications, so to change WhatsApp's notification settings you need to open the WhatsApp app, and then press your device's <kbd>Menu</kbd> button (or press the `...` ellipses icon in the top right of the screen)

[image]

Then select **Settings**

[image]

And then select **Notifications**, you can then see the various options that WhatsApp has for alerting you about different types of messages.

[image]

Comment: Hi geffchang, there is no ... button on my screen. Only 2 buttons appear- one for a new chat and another for search. I also tries pressing the Menu button...nothing happens. Is there some other way to access this?

Answer (score 1):

The Samsung Galaxy SIII has three hardware buttons below the screen (from left to right: Menu key, Home Key, and Back Key). You can access the device settings by clicking the Menu key after swiping the screen to unlock it and then clicking on Settings on the menu that pops up on the screen. Once you click on the WhatsApp icon on the Home Screen or on one of the Apps Screen of the Android OS, you can also hit the Menu key to bring up the WhatsApp Options and click there. Android devices also have what is called a Notification Drawer. When you receive a WhatsApp message it will appear in the Notifications Drawer which you can slide out onto your screen by swiping your finger from the top of the screen downwards.